# Solving a congruence mod 255

Tags: number-theory

I would like to find  the integer solutions of $128x^2+y^2 \equiv 0 \mod 255$

Comment: Solve it for $\bmod 3,5,17$ and use the Chinese Remainder theorem.  Each of those is small enough to do by hand if you want.

Comment: thanks @rossmillikan I was able to get quick results from wolfram alpha so I wouldn't have to do it by hand but wont   compute mod 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We factor $255=3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17$ and solve it for each modulus.
$\bmod 3$ we need $x,y$ to both be $0$ or both be non-$0$.
$\bmod 5$ we need $x,y$ to both be $0$
$\bmod 17$ they can both be $0$ or there are eight pairs like $x=\pm 1, y=\pm 5$

We can combine these.
$\bmod 85$ the above give $(x,y)=(35,5),(35,80),(50,5),(50,80)$
adding in the restriction $\bmod 3$ gives $\bmod 255$
 $(x,y)=(35,5),(205,5),(35,175),(205,175),(120,90)$ from the first.

Comment: $(5,25)$ is a solution. I've counted 165 solutions with $x,y\ge 0$.

Comment: That is right as there are $5$ solutions $\bmod 3$, $17$ solutions $\bmod 17$, and $1$ solution $\bmod 5$.  Multiplying these gives $165$

Comment: Got it, thanks.